# Any way to fetch a segue (and destination view controller) programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue, uistoryboardsegue, 3dtouch

Is there any way to fetch a segue created in storyboard programmatically outside of `-[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`?

Ideally I'd like to be able to created segues in storyboard, fetch those segues in code, and retrieve those segues' destination view controllers. For me this is a little cleaner and easier to maintain than using view controller identifiers, e.g., `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"]`.

An example of use would be in implementing a 3D touch deep-press gesture to peek-and-pop a view controller that is otherwise accessed via a traditional segue.

Comment: The segues don't actually get created until you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` so there isn't really anything to fetch.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a segue programmatically you can use following code, it will return array of segue.

**Objective c**

```
NSArray *segueTemplates = [(UIStoryboardSegue *) self valueForKey:@"storyboardSegueTemplates"] ;
  for (UIStoryboardSegue *string in segueTemplates) {
    NSLog(@"%@", string.identifier);
  }
```

**Swift**

```
let segueTemplates = self.valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates")
```